# Joomla url redirect, 404 not working

Tags: redirect, joomla

I'm maintaining a Joomla site (v3.5.1) and noticed a redirecting issue. For example, 
/some-directory/ contains some-page.html, another-page.html, more-page.html.

When there is a typo such as /some-directory/some-ppppage.html it doesn't trigger 404. Instead it loads /some-directory/ (/some-directory/ default page).

Is there a way to fix this? I don't think this is a default behaviour by Joomla.

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293878/how-do-i-get-non-existing-joomla-urls-redirected-to-our-404-error-page

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is sh404SEF doing this with the similar URLs plugin. Disable the similar URLs and you should be fine. If you don't have sh404SEF installed, then you must have another SEF plugin causing this (check your non-core system plugins).

Note: The sh404SEF similar URL plugin can dramatically slow down your website (see [this post](http://www.itoctopus.com/warning-the-similar-urls-plugin-will-slow-down-your-joomla-website)). It is strongly recommended that you turn it off. It's also not that good for SEO when you have many "similar" links redirecting to the same URL.

Comment: I only see "System - SEF" extension and nothing else. Is there anything I can do find out? Thanks.